# Zombie folders coming back from the dead with Docker running on WSL2

Tags: docker, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

This issue is really strange, but I've no idea how to resolve it. I'm running Win10 and I've got WSL2 on it. When I start Docker with it using the "WSL 2 Based engine", it retrieves some deleted folders out of nowhere. I delete them every single time and after I've restarted my PC and started up Docker again, the folders are back.

There are absolutely no docker containers running ("docker ps" returns nothing) so it couldn't be that some rogue volume definition is being ran along with some container. The folders also only appear once I start up Docker.

The directory inside of which the zombie folders appear is also the source for a Mutagen volume when the containers are running, but as I said - no containers are running.

Comment: Just an idea off the top of my head since I've never used the WSL2 version of Docker (yet), I know that the Docker Desktop in Windows has a Resources/Shared Folders section that you manually choose which folders are shared; wondering if maybe you have some shared folders marked in Docker, and Docker recreates those folders even if you manually delete them?

Comment: Nope nothing like that. I don't see anything like that in Docker for Desktop settings either.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and resolved it by running Troubleshoot from Docker for Windows and purge data on WSL2.

I've not found a solution to selectively clear just that one folder that keeps getting raised from the dead.